# Graphical Layout missing for xml layout file Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have opened up a android project but the xml file graphical layout is not being shown..I have searched on stack overflow and found that it can be fixed by clicking create in top right ..but it is greyed out and does not come up...even if i fill all the details of locale,editing config,change android API level to 2.2/3.0 ..The file opens in xml view..Screenshots are attached..
Can anyone let me know what is the problem and its solution.
If the answer is there somewhere on stack overflow..kindly provide the link..i will delete the question..i wasn't able to find the answer myself..

[image: Graphical Layout]

[image]

Comment: it looks like you have the file opened twice... if so, maybe try closing one before going to the Graphical Layout tab?

Comment: Second question... is this happening with all layout files or just the one?

Comment: just this one is having problem..and second file is of another project..

Comment: I've had this happen to me aswell, its a very strange bug. Get out of all windows and right click on which file you want to open. Go to Open With > Android Common XML Editor. If that doesnt work, get out of all widows again then, Project > Clean. If that doesn't work restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Open With > Android Common XML editor will not work.

The two tabs was missing because of the theme. Try to set your theme back to the default one. **Eclipse > Preferences > General > Appearance > Theme combobox > Mac**